# Php Array not Working With Varible But Working With Direct Values

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to making random teams so i use below function

```
 $candidates =
 array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);

function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3)
{
    shuffle($candidates);
    $teams = array_map(function($chunk){
        return implode(",", $chunk);
    }, array_chunk($candidates, $team_size));

    return implode("\n", $teams);
}

$ss = print_r(getTeam($candidates));
```

the output for above code is working fine like my output is

> 8,5,6 6,3,1 5,1,2

but if i working below code

```
 $np="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21";

 $candidates = array($np);
           function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3) {
 shuffle($candidates);
 $teams = array_map(function($chunk){
     return implode(",", $chunk);
 }, array_chunk($candidates, $team_size));

 return implode("\n", $teams); }

 $ss = print_r(getTeam($candidates));
```

then i am getting simply this output

> output: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21

i dont know why its not work everytime is same only i made small change

Comment: you need to explode the comma separated string if you want to use it as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is your candidates is a string not an array so you need to make it array before passing it to function so you need to do is

```
<?php 
$np="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21";
$candidates = explode(',',$np);
print_r($candidates);
function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3) {
    shuffle($candidates);
    $teams = array_map(function($chunk){
    return implode(",", $chunk);
    },
    array_chunk($candidates, $team_size));
    return implode("\n", $teams); 
}
 print_r(getTeam($candidates));
?>
```

This will work fine. You need to explode your string

Answer (score 0):

Php array accepts a mixed of parameters.

In your case,

`array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);` with 21 parameter,

while `$np="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21"; $candidates = array($np);` only accept one parameter.

`"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21"` is different with `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21`.

To create an array from seperator seperated string, use `explode`.

Refer to [PHP ARRAY DOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

> array ([ mixed $... ] ) : array
>
> Syntax "index => values", separated by commas, define index and values. index may be of type string or integer. When index is omitted,
>   an integer index is automatically generated, starting at 0. If index
>   is an integer, next generated index will be the biggest integer index
>   + 1. Note that when two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first.
>
> Having a trailing comma after the last defined array entry, while unusual, is a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
simply pass array in $np and use in $candidates,

```html
$np=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21);

 $candidates = $np;
function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3) {
 shuffle($candidates);
 $teams = array_map(function($chunk){
     return implode(",", $chunk);
 }, array_chunk($candidates, $team_size));

 return implode("\n", $teams); }

 $ss = print_r(getTeam($candidates));
```